# Call a javascript function after an entire animation happens

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm struggling with function callback and timeout in Javascript.

I've some DIV, and those have to "pulse" one after another.
Their values are in an array.
This array is incremented every time a DIV pulses.

The red pulse so gameArr = ["red"] and so on...

```
var k = 0;
    setTimeout(function(){
      for(let value of gameArr){
          toPulse(value)
        k++;
            console.log(gameArr);
      if(k == gameArr.length){
        playerTurn()
      }
      }
      },2000);
```

Every time I use this all the DIVs pulse together and not one after another.

Comment: Try `setInterval`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here, you have your `for` loop *inside* your `setTimeout()` function.
What you could do is have an iterator variable and place a `setTimeout()` *inside* your `for` loop.

See something like this :

```
let k = 0;
const interval = 2000;

for (let value of gameArr) {

    setTimeout(() => {
        toPulse(value)
    }, k * interval);

    k++;
    console.log(gameArr);
    if (k == gameArr.length) {
        playerTurn()
    }

}
```

Don't forget Javascript is *async*, which means the `setTimeout` function will execute itself totally outside of the rest of the *sync* code. With the code above, you create as many *timeouts* as you have elements in your array, each with a delay which is proportionnal to their place in the array.

Comment: It worked... thanks a lot.
Is it always necessary to multiply for the array index? (k)

Comment: Multiplying by the index allows the script to make every animation appear one at a time.

Comment: See, for the first element, the timeOut will be 0*2000, so it will start immediatly. For the next one, it will start after 2000 milliseconds. The second one will start after 4000 milliseconds, and so on...

Comment: so the timeout need an increment to work in successive steps... ok